# Problem setting alias, ~/.bash_aliases file not found

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, alias

I was trying to setup a permanent alias. but `~/.bash_aliases` file not found on my system. I have checked the `bashrc` file and it shows `bash_aliases` are enabled. I tried creating a new file in the same name in home directory and putting the aliases. But it also didn't work. Any solution to set a permanent alias?

Also i would like to know whether I can set an alias for shell that I created and it is residing in some other path. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I have seen that question earlier. But my problem is different. I am unable to locate the `bashrc_aliases` file. I am looking for that solution here, and not the answer for how to set the alias.

Comment: what do you mean "`bash_aliases` are enabled"? How do you know the file isn't found?

Comment: @Trengot I have the idea that I have to keep my aliases in `bash_aliases` file in `alias name='command'` format. And in order to tell the terminal to look at this file when I request an alias, two lines of codes ( `if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi` ) needs to be put in `bashrc`. In this way I know that `bash_aliases` is enabled.

Comment: Ok. Do you have a file called `.bash_aliases` in your home directory?

Comment: No. And that is my problem and I have mentioned it in the question heading already :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lines

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then 
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

mean if the file `.bash_aliases` exists then use it. In your case it doesn't exist so it's ignored.

If you want to add to it just create the file. How you do that is up to you but I'd suggest `gedit ~/.bash_aliases` from the terminal. Add in any aliases you want, then save the file and open a new terminal. Your new aliases should be working.

If you want the new aliases in an existing terminal use `source ~/.bash_aliases`.

EDIT: I've just noticed you've referred to the file by both `bash_aliases` and `bashrc_aliases`. It doesn't matter which you use as long as the filename matches the line in `.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't knew that after creating the alias I have to open a new terminal to execute it. Thanks a bundle for taking your time and mentioning it.

Comment: Could you please tell me whether is it possible to set an alias to an `sh` file by specifying its path?

Comment: Yes. For instance `alias foo='~/bar/foo.sh'` would let you run foo.sh just by typing foo. Note that you'd need `foo.sh` to be executable and to have an appropriate shebang line.